# Meteor Icons and Splashscreens in mobile-config.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, icons

I'm changing the icons and splashscreens and I get a large error when i try running on android:

> WARNING: iphone: unknown key in App.icons configuration. The key may
>   be deprecated. WARNING: android_ldpi: unknown key in App.icons
>   configuration. The key may be deprecated. WARNING: iphone: unknown key
>   in App.launchScreens configuration. The key may be deprecated.
>   WARNING: android_ldpi_portrait: unknown key in App.launchScreens
>   configuration. The key may be deprecated. WARNING:
>   android_ldpi_landscape: unknown key in App.launchScreens
>   configuration. The key may be deprecated.
>
> C:\Users\FS399777\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:116
>         throw error;
>               ^ Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\defaultApp\resources\iOS\Resources\icons\icon-120.png'
>       at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:696:18)
>       at Object.wrapper [as stat] (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1368:35)
>       at Object.files.copyFile (C:\tools\fs\files.js:560:23)
>       at C:\tools\cordova\builder.js:343:13
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (C:\Users\FS399777\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
>       at CordovaBuilder.configureAndCopyImages (C:\tools\cordova\builder.js:323:7)
>       at CordovaBuilder.writeConfigXmlAndCopyResources (C:\tools\cordova\builder.js:291:12)
>       at CordovaProject.prepareFromAppBundle (C:\tools\cordova\project.js:189:13)
>       at C:\tools\cordova\runner.js:78:27
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
>       at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
>       at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
>       at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
>       at CordovaRunner.prepareProject (C:\tools\cordova\runner.js:77:18)
>       at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:682:25
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
>       at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
>       at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
>       at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
>       at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
>       at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:681:39
>       at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:693:9
>       at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:679:7)
>       at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:887:28)
>       at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:411:12

Here is my mobile-config.js

```
App.icons({
  // iOS
  'iphone': 'resources/iOS/Resources/icons/Icon-60.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/iOS/Resources/icons/Icon-120.png',
  'iphone_3x': 'resources/iOS/Resources/icons/Icon-180.png',
  'ipad': 'resources/iOS/Resources/icons/Icon-76.png',
  'ipad_2x': 'resources/iOS/Resources/icons/Icon-152.png',

  // Android
  'android_ldpi': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png',
  'android_mdpi': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png',
  'android_hdpi': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png',
  'android_xhdpi': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png'
});

App.launchScreens({
  // iOS
  'iphone': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default~iphone.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default@2x~iphone_640x960.png',
  'iphone5': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone_640x1136.png',
  'iphone6': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-750@2x~iphone6-portrait_750x1334.png',
  'iphone6p_portrait': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-1242@3x~iphone6s-portrait_1242x2208.png',
  'iphone6p_landscape': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-1242@3x~iphone6s-landscape_2208x1242.png',

  'ipad_portrait': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad_768x1024.png',
  'ipad_portrait_2x': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad_1536x2048.png',
  'ipad_landscape': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad_1024x768.png',
  'ipad_landscape_2x': 'resources/iOS/Resources/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad_2048x1536.png',

  // Android
  'android_ldpi_portrait': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-ldpi/splash.png',
  'android_ldpi_landscape': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-land-ldpi/splash.png',
  'android_mdpi_portrait': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-mdpi/splash.png',
  'android_mdpi_landscape': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-land-mdpi/splash.png',
  'android_hdpi_portrait': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png',
  'android_hdpi_landscape': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-land-hdpi/splash.png',
  'android_xhdpi_portrait': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-xhdpi/splash.png',
  'android_xhdpi_landscape': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/splash.png'
  'android_xxhdpi_portrait': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/splash.png',
  'android_xxhdpi_landscape': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-land-xxhdpi/splash.png'
  'android_xxxhdpi_portrait': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/splash.png',
  'android_xxxhdpi_landscape': 'resources/Android/res/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/splash.png'
});
```

What happens after I try to build the app. This error shows up and all of my files in "resources" folder disappear. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: 'iphone', 'android_ldpi' keys cannot be used anymore I think. Please see the latest docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-icons